# auth() is not working in controller when coming from vue

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a store method in a controller. now for a field, I am inserting auth()->user()->id. when I am submitting the form from a normal blade, it works fine. but when I am submitting the form from a vue component, it is returning 500 error when I am using auth()->user()->id. instead of this, if i write just 4 or 10 or any static data, it is working fine again!

Comment: If you deal with vue component and make it protected then use oAuth and implement it (JWT, passport etc)

Comment: See the error in network tab and post it in here

Comment: How do you authenticate your user? Using session? How did you submit your form?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the id you submit is in an invalid format and your backend script fails on it. Try to see first if you really have the id and not null or undefined. If so, then see if the id is int or string in your js and then finally see what datatype your backend accepts. If this does not work, please provide some code. You can also see your apache log, what error it throws when you try to access your endpoint.